# C++ Protobuf undefined reference to constructor/destructor

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

When attempting to compile code calling a small protobuf class (which itself successfully compiles), I get a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `ggf::Block::Leveling()'
undefined reference to `ggf::Block::~Leveling()'
```

The line of code which causes this error:

```
ggf::Block blockMessage;
```

The protobuf:

```
package ggf;
message Leveling {
        required int32 type         = 1;
        optional uint64 blockNumber = 2;
        optional bytes blockData    = 3;
}
```

And finally, my build line, config flags from pkg-config:

```
g++ -o send sendercode.cpp -std=c++11 -lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread -g
```

Alternatively, I can create a pointer to this Block class, which successfully compiles but then segfaults when setting the type,

```
ggf::Block *blockRequest;
blockRequest->set_type(10);   //SIGSEGV
```

Debugging reveals the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400d66 in ggf::Block::set_has_type (this=0x0) at block.pb.h:172
```

It's acting as if it's not initialized.. did I miss an initialization step?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `-lpthread ` is unnecessary when you have `-pthread`, in fact you should *not* do `-lpthread`.

Comment: your segfault is caused by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should also add `block.pb.cc` to the compile file list:

```
g++ -o send sendercode.cpp block.pb.cc -std=c++11 -lprotobuf -pthread -g
```

Comment: I was linking against protoc (-lprotoc) instead of protobuf (-lprotobuf), this may help some of you

Answer (score 1):

Look at your includes, this problem would occur if you only include the "block.pb.h" file.